# Facebook comments limit in a given amount of time

Tags: facebook-comments

Does anyone know what is the limit like you can only post 300 comments in an hour or 200 or 500? Does anyone know the exact number and the amount of time?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the exact number but I've been "limited," that is, prohibited from commenting for two days. No, my account is not "restricted" BUT through this new FB censoring measure, it is. Sneaky MF'ers.